# Display of ConfusionMatrixPlot depends on Stylesheet

Tags: bugs, stylesheet, machine-learning

I´m using Classify and do the testing via ClassifierMeasurements. Now I observed that ConfusionMatrixPlot is not shown correctly when using StyleSheet Report(default). Maybe you can reproduce (example from documentation)

```
trainingset = {1 -> "A", 2 -> "A", 3.5 -> "B", 4 -> "B"};
c = Classify[trainingset];
cm = ClassifierMeasurements[c, trainingset];
cm["ConfusionMatrixPlot"]
```

Everything fine, but when I change to StyleSheet-> StandardReport the matrix is not shown properly. Am I doing a foolish mistake or is there anything I have overseen and only have to "push a button"?. Working picture from my problem, here:
[image]

Comment: That's interesting ... I can reproduce it.

Comment: I get the same with 10.02 on OS X. I will be something to do with options in OutPut or Graphics or similar.